# Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005) on VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

First i did looked at other threads and all the answer specified were didn't helped, as i was getting this error only for specific SQL execution. Whenever i am trying to run SQL with select * from dual i was getting below error message.

[image]

Below is my VBA Code

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    StrCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
            "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
            "(HOST=dhotname)(PORT=1521))" & _
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=APSQ))); uid=username; pwd=password;"
cn.Open (StrCon)
vSQL = "select * from request" 
rs.Open vSQL, cn
```

Comment: You really want us to help you without you providing any code?

Comment: There is nothing in this question or the answer which is going to be helpful to anyone else - VTC.

Comment: If you Google "80004005 Microsoft" you'll get some clues. Sometimes it's as simple as the database is locked by another "user."

Comment: @Scott to answer you this is just SQL issue, so what code you are expecting. @ Bryan don't you think i tried this already, i did Google but if you see answer it all talks about DSN which in my case is correct.

Comment: I am not expert in writing here, but what i found is in my SQL i just had column with TImeStamp which gave me this error and after removing that it worked for me. My intention was to give some hint to others, to check there SQL...

Comment: I am expecting you to show the code that is generating this error of course. Perhaps you have a syntax error in your SQL statement. Perhaps you haven't opened the connection. Etc. We can't help you with just an error code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have added Code which failed for me in post, Thanks for correction.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I am putting solution here, which worked for me. In other similar post it was more over connectivity issue, but in my scenario it was one of the column in table i am trying to access. In my table i had column which is having timeStamp and that's the column was causing above error, when i removed or used formatting for that column it worked without exception. I wonder if this error would have been more explanatory, as i spend time on trying other stuff instead of just fixing my SQL.

Solution:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    StrCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
            "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
            "(HOST=dhotname)(PORT=1521))" & _
            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=APSQ))); uid=username; pwd=password;"
cn.Open (StrCon)
vSQL = "select request_id,user_name from request" 
rs.Open vSQL, cn
```

Now if you look at above example i have specified exact column names, the issue here was REC_DT column  which had time value. Either you can convert that value or remove column, for me that value was not required so just removed from my SQL and it worked.

[image]